# Label in CustomCell stays nil

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I created a custom UITableViewCell with an UILabel in it.

In the cellForRowAtIndexPath method I initialise the custom cell and give the UILabel a value.

While the custom cell is loaded (the heights of the cells are higher than default cells), I can't seem to give the UILabel a value.

**SBDownloadCell.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SBDownloadCell : UITableViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *title;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIProgressView *progressbar;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *details;

- (IBAction)pause:(id)sender;

@end
```

**SBDownloadCell.m**

```
#import "SBDownloadCell.h"

@implementation SBDownloadCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

- (IBAction)pause:(id)sender {
}
@end
```

**SBViewController.m**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SBDownload";

    SBDownloadCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[SBDownloadCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    SBDownload *dwnld = [[SBDownload alloc] init];
    dwnld = [SBdownloads objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    //cell.title.text = [dwnld name];
    cell.title.text = @"Test";
    cell.progressbar.progress = [dwnld percentDone];
    cell.details.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f MB of %f MB completed, %@", [dwnld completed], [dwnld length], [dwnld eta]];

    return cell;
}
```

**Storyboard**

[image]

I break just after `cell.title.text = @"Test";` and still this is what I see:

[image]

What could it be?

*note: i use Xcode DP-5 with iOS7*

Comment: Could you post some code from the SBDownloadCell? Everything here looks ok

Comment: I updated my question with SBDownloadCell

Comment: is it a xib ? because I don't see you loading it from it

Comment: Please post a screenshot of your storyboard setup, and I will update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see your properties are marked with `IBOutlet`, which means you have an Interface Builder file (either xib or storyboard) with your table view cell. Make sure to give the correct cell identifier in Interface Builder to the prototype cell in your table view. You should not be calling `initWithStyle:`. If `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` returns nil when using a `UITableViewController` and storyboards, this means incorrect setup, as `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` should always return a cell (it creates the new one if it has to).

To elaborate a bit further, when using xibs or storyboards, a table view cell's `initWithStyle:` will never be called. When a nib is loaded, the correct init method is `initWithCoder:`.

The problem is in `static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SBDownload";`. In your storyboard, you have set up the identifier as `SBDownloadCell`.

Comment: I have a storyboard and the cell identifier is correct. I think you misread my problem. I am getting a correct cell. The problem is that an **`UILabel` inside that cell stays nil** and doesn't get a value assigned.

Comment: My god, don't I feel stupid right now.. Spent 4 hours for this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No worries, it happens to the best. ;)

Comment: @Galip what's the solution? I didn't get it. My Label's are also nil

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate your `UILabel`s and `UIProgressView`. Right now you set properties for them, but in your `-initWithStyle` method you need to call things like

```
self.title = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:etc...];
```

If you do this for each of your properties on SBDownloadCell, the labels should be allocated properly.

Comment: The weird thing is that I have another custom `UITableViewCell` and it's exactly the same way as this one, except for the fact that it works. Even without allocating.

I created my `UILabel`s and `UIProgressView` in storyboard. Should I get the dimensions for the frame from there?

Comment: OH I thought you were creating it programmatically. I've never used story boards for table view cells before, but I know that when you use nibs, you should call:
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"filename" owner: options:];
when you're checking for a nil cell

Answer (score 0):

If you custom your prototype cells in Storyboard, you need to present your TableViewController with segue in storyboard, or if you you need to present the TableViewController by programming, you need to use instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: method,

```
- (IBAction)showTableView:(id)sender
{
    UIStoryboard *storybaord = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPad" bundle:nil];
    LJTableViewController *vc = (LJTableViewController*)[storybaord
                                                         instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TableViewControllerID"];
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

if you initiate TableViewController with [TableViewContrller new], this will let you get an nil label in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath mehtod.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter same problem but my identifier is correct for creating custom cell and show data in IBOutlets custom lable, but after cell allocation lables values are null. So for this I need to add method of tableview for showing lables values

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(DropViewTableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
    cell.lblHSNCode.text = objClass.HSNCode;
  }
```